# How to get instance number

Tags: java

Is there way how to get instance number or id, I mean that what you can see in eclipse Debug>Variables window after class name in value column.

Thanks

Comment: I believe that number is just the memory address of the object. `hashCode` might return this number, or a munged version of it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java object ID in jvm](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3289550/java-object-id-in-jvm)

Comment: I don't mean memory address, I mean the number of instance not object. It is possible that the number is generated by eclipse.

Answer (score 7):

See [`System.identityHashCode`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#identityHashCode%28java.lang.Object%29) which returns the number that would be returned if `Object.hashCode` had not been overridden on an object.  It is not a perfect proxy for identity since multiple objects might have the same identity hash code, but it is pretty useful for debugging.

Answer (score 1):

By default, debugger shows you the result of `toString()` method with the hashCode of the object. So, you can see the value by executing `hashCode()` method.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you're refering to Objects toString() implementation.:

```
return getClass().getName() + "@" + Integer.toHexString(hashCode());
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm wrong, but I don't think instances of a class are numbered. I have searched many times for a way to get instances of a particular class and according to my searches, it would be impossible. Instances have an address, but I see no use for a class instance number (objects are not sorted by class in memory AFAIK). Note that you can always create a mechanism for giving numbers to you instances of a particular class. Have a static count in the class and give its value to each new instance you create (in the constructor) and increment it each time. That would be a way to differentiate instances.