# How to store entity with setted UUID?

Tags: java, sql-server, hibernate, jpa, uuid

I'm using MS SQL Server + Hibernate (JPA, more precisely, with EntityManager)  and i faced with the problem: I need to store entity into appropriate table in my DB; this table has `uniqueidentifier` as primary key; and storing entity already has UUID (it's primary key), with witch it should be inserted into the DB.

Problem is that when i try to `merge` my entity, hibernate do some magic and store my entity with *another* UUID value. So, when I fetch this entity from db and take a look on it ID, I see inappropriate value.
So, I want to tell hibernate not to do that (or, maybe, there is another solution?).

My entity class:

```
public class Entity extends BaseEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid2")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "uuid2", strategy = "uuid2")
    @Column(name = "id_column")
    private UUID uuId;

    // other fields, getters, setters
}
```

Also, I have one more 'annoyance': my IDE and my DB browser shows me another ID in that column. I mean, when I stop my app in the debug mode and look at the id of an entity, I see different value from a value in the database.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Not a Hibernate expert, but why are you using `merge`? Shouldn't you just use `save` instead? `save` should preserve the initial ID.

Comment: @dimoniy Maybe, I was incorrect with terms I used. I'm using EntityManager API to provide my operations, which have `persist` and `merge` operations to write something into DB.

Comment: how are you doing your merge?  Why aren't you using a strategy of guid? That is usually more appropriate for SQL Server.

Comment: @TerrenceCurran Can you tell me more/share link about using guid strategy?

Comment: _"So, when I fetch this entity from db and take a look on it ID, I see inappropriate value."_ How do you fetch it? By the _old_ id?

Comment: @DraganBozanovic no, I fetch entity with all another entites, when I reload my page, and if I open it - I see another id - not old value and not passed to store value.

Comment: You are sure it is not the [Eclipse debugger object id](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12578608/how-to-get-eclipse-debug-id-of-an-object)? Are you sure that the primary key has changed?

Comment: @DraganBozanovic I'm using IDEA, but I'm shure, that it is exactly entity id. And yes, it has changed.