# Find the object by Eclipse debugger ID

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, identifier

Eclipse's Debug panel shows a list of threads.  If a thread is paused and is waiting for an object's lock, then Eclipse will display `waiting for: (id=101)`.  How do I use Eclipse to show me the object for id 101?

Note: This is an ID assigned by the debugger and has nothing to do with `System.identityHashCode()` or `hashCode()`.

Note: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3289550/java-object-id-in-jvm) asks how to get the ID of the object given the object.  My question is the reverse.