# Eclipse Debugger - Watch object by ID

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging

The Eclipse debugger assigns some random number to each watched object (in the debug view shown with (id=123))

[image: Eclipse variable view]

Is there a way the watch the value of an object by the debugger ID, independent of the current stack/scope (as long as the object was not collected)?

There is a similar old question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51294224/find-the-object-by-eclipse-debugger-id), but with no answers. Maybe there some new developments...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to do this, if there is code with a variable referencing the object

1. Select the variable in the code editor
2. Open the context menu on the variable in the code editor
3. Select “Inspect”

[image: context menu]

4. Hit “[Ctrl]+[Shift]+I” to add it to the expression view

[image: Inspect popup]

5. Now you can see the value of the object, even if the variable is reassigned.

[image: expression view]